# java String array in ascending order

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, text-files

I'd like to have the list be in ascending order via "sortAscending" and then send "showArray" and "sortAscending" to a textfile. "sortAscending(list);" isn't showing anything when running it, and there are no syntax errors.

```
sortAscending(list);
public static String[] sortAscending(String[] names)
{
    String temp;
    int passNum, i, result;
    for(passNum=1; passNum < 10; passNum++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i<(10-passNum); i++)
        {
            result=names[i].compareToIgnoreCase(names[i+1]);
            if(result>0)
            {
                temp=names[i];
                names[i]=names[i+1];
                names[i+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return names;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "send showArray and sortAscending to a text file"? Do you mean "write the current order of the list to the text file"?

Comment: Is sorting a part of assignment? If not then instead of using `Bubble Sort`, either try using some good algorithm like __Quicksort__, or else use an inbuilt function from `java.util` package, `Arrays.sort(array);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Print sorted list 
sortAscending(list);
```

`sortAscending` is not printing anything. It just sorts the list. You probably want to

```
// Sort the list and print it
showArray(sortAscending(list));
```

Comment: Thanks! Any advice how I can send unsorted and sorted data to "output.txt"? I can only get it to send the sorted data.

Comment: That's because your sort function destroys the original array. Output it before sorting or make a copy of the array.